# Getting Codeigniter CSRF token without a form?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have CSRF protection enabled on my site, but the only time the CSRF token is placed in a hidden field is when `form_close()` is used. I am posting data via ajax and need to send the CSRF as well to prevent the 500 errors.

I thought there was a way to explicitly embed the CSRF token into the page, but I can't seem to find it.

How can I get the CSRF token when there isn't a form on the page?

Comment: [Ajax form + CSRF results in a failing request](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/230264/#1042793)

Comment: Sam in incorrect, set the token on the page via $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); and then just pull the _TOKEN value, ex. data: {
                    _TOKEN: $('input[name="_TOKEN"]').val()},

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can get the CSRF token name and value via the security class:

```
$this->security->get_csrf_hash();
$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
```

Comment: Weird, couldn't find that in the documentation, but that's exactly what I was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 12):

Add it to the form this way

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows you how to enable CSRF Attack mode :

```js
<script>
    
  var cct = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>';
  var get_csrf_token_name = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>';
  
   $.ajaxSetup({
   type:'post',
  data:{ <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?> :cct}
   });
   
  
    var siteurl = '<?= site_url()?>';        
       
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer in 2023.

I solved this by adding `protected \CodeIgniter\Security\Security $security;` property into my `BaseController` class, and assigning the core security class into the property when the `initController` method is called.

```
...
// Do Not Edit This Line
parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

// Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
$this->security = new Security(config('Security'));
...
```