# jQuery .post method returns empty response from same domain

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to use jQuery .post method in CodeIgniter; Even though I send request to the same domain and there should be no cross-domain issue, I get empty response. Here is my code:

```
$('#send-transaction').click(function(){
    $.post('/authorized/test1',function(data){alert(data);});
});
```

And function test1() of authorized controller looks like:

```
function test1() {echo "test";}
```

How can I get it to return the function's output (in this case, string "test")?

## UPDATE

The reason is in invalid controller; Moving discussion to another question:

[Codeigniter controller not returning requested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569210/codeigniter-controller-not-returning-requested-function)

Comment: What's going on in your browser's console?

Comment: You don't see any request being made to /authorized/test1? If not, that is where you need to start because you're not sending anything.

Comment: I mean, I can see the request and response and everything as usual (no errors), only response is blank instead of a string.

Comment: It even triggers an alert pop-up as expected, but no data in it. This is weird.

Comment: If the response is blank then the alert will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter includes protection from Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks. This means any non-GET requests need to include a special token to tell the server that they're legitimate.

Here's an SO question that shows [how to get that token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387091/getting-codeigniter-csrf-token-without-a-form) without having to render a form on the page, and [here's one with a bunch of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269439/how-to-include-csrf-from-codeigniter-into-ajax-data) showing how to integrate that with an ajax request.

Comment: I included the following lines of code to the view file from where I make jQuery .post request:
    $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
    $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
Still I get the same result - empty response. Do I need to somehow incorporate the token value into my post request?

Comment: I included the code to the view file from where I make the request. Still I get the same result - empty response. Do I need to somehow incorporate the token value into the request?

Comment: Yes, you need to include it in the request. I added a link to another SO question that shows a bunch of ways to do that.

Comment: Ok, now my code looks like this: 
`var tokenname = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>';
var tokenvalue = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';
$.post('/authorized/test1',{tokenname:tokenvalue},function(data){ alert(data);})`
Still getting the same result: request status 200 OK, response blank.

Answer (score 0):

Change PHP code as below:

```
function test1() {echo "test"; exit;}
```